# Browser interprets hyperlink specified href as a totally different url

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I'm experiencing a strange behavior in a HTML front-end page.

In that page:
    https://www.cindycottage.com/novita/nastro-jolis-boutons.html
the buttons in the slider placed in the sidebar have a strange behavior.

In the HTML code is specified an attribute
    onclick="window.location='some link'"
but the browser points to another url. Hovering the mouse on the button shows the wrong url in the status bar. I verified with the browser inspector that no javascript is changing the url dinamically.

Comment: But the whole page is relevant code, because obviously this is a problem due to a conflict between two page elements somewhere.

Comment: So? That's completely irrelevant. If it's too big, it's up to you to produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending on the onclick attribute in the for the link 'return false;'
Example:

```
onclick="window.location='https://www.cindycottage.com/promozioni';return false;"
```

The problem is that the button element has also a binding for the submit event which gets invoked when you click on it. Return false; overides this default behaviour;

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the button inside a form. I didn't know this caveat :-) the return false solved.

Answer (score 1):

The button is placed inside a form. So, when you click it, you will go to the `url` specified in the `action` attribute of the `form` tag.

You can do it using jQuery like this:

```
$('#id_of_the_button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location = 'Some url';
});
```

Replace `id_of_the_button` and `Some url` with desired values.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the button inside a form. I didn't know this caveat :-)